# Wrong value set when use lldb expr in Xcode8.0 and debug with iPhone6 Plus

Tags: xcode8, lldb

I use this `expr` to modify the speed value:

```
expr (void)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] layer] setSpeed:0.9f]
```

But the value set is -2.

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

---

I try this command on another app, the result is correct....

Comment: One possible source of difference here is that if your app does "@import UIKit", that leaves an indication in the debug info that you've done this, and lldb as of Xcode8.0 will use that indication to automatically import UIKit into the expression parser's context for you.  But if you do "#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>", there's no easy way for lldb to know you are using UIKit, and so you have to do it manually as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that lldb is getting the definition of these functions from the ObjC runtime type information which is incomplete.  If it has the wrong signature for the function, it won't pass the arguments correctly.

What happens if you do:

```
(lldb) @import UIKit
```

then run your expression?